# Query returns different results depending on number of tables in FROM

Tags: sql, oracle

I have several tables in a exercise, lets call them animals, prizes and exhibitions.

When I write following simple query

```
SELECT animals.name FROM animals;
```

I get 8 results, all names from the animals table.

However when I write

```
SELECT animals.name FROM animals, exhibitions, prizes;
```

I get over six hundred results, all of them names from animals table, just multiple times.
Why is that happening? I specified the column and the table in the SELECT command. I do not want any data from other tables.

Only table animals has a column called name.

Edit: Sorry I asked.

Comment: You are doing a cross join here, will return animals' number of rows multiplied with exhibitions' number of rows multiplied with prizes' number of rows.

Comment: If you don't want data from those other tables why do you list them?  You get CROSS JOINs because there's no join-condition. The number returned is the number of rows from each table multiplied.

Comment: It's called Cartesian join.

Comment: @stee1rat, the SQL term is `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: Normalization is not the answer, will still get many more rows than expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing a union join, which 'multiplies' the tuples in all the tables regardless of whether or not they have common fields. You need to specify a join field in your SQL, else you get this type of join.

Answer (score 0):

when you join several tables you will got the result of all tables, in your example you got not only animal table , you aslo got exhibitions and prizes.

to solve that use a specifque condition example  .. where animal.name = exhibitions.place

read more about joins fromt oracle [document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm) ( left joins , outer joins) its really helpful